# TSQL - Dynamically generate queries from a record set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Sample Data:

```
DECLARE @Tbl_List TABLE
    (
        [PSchemaName] sysname
      , [PTableName]  sysname
      , [PColumnName] sysname
      , [FSchemaName] sysname
      , [FTableName]  sysname
      , [FColumnName] sysname
      , [ColumnOrder] TINYINT
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Tbl_List
VALUES
    ( 'emp', 'emphdr1', 'id', 'emp', 'empdtl1', 'hdrid', 1 )
  , ( 'emp', 'emphdr2', 'id', 'emp', 'empdtl2', 'hdrid', 1 )
  , ( 'emp', 'emphdr2', 'key', 'emp', 'empdtl2', 'hdrkey', 2 )
  , ( 'emp', 'emphdr3', 'id', 'emp', 'empdtl3', 'hdrid', 1 )
  , ( 'emp', 'emphdr3', 'key1', 'emp', 'empdtl3', 'hdrkey1', 2 )
  , ( 'emp', 'emphdr3', 'key2', 'emp', 'empdtl3', 'hdrkey2', 3 )
  , ( 'emp', 'emphdr3', 'id', 'emp', 'empdtl4', 'hdrid', 1 )
  , ( 'emp', 'emphdr3', 'key1', 'emp', 'empdtl4', 'hdrkey1', 2 ) ;
```

---

```
PSchemaName PTableName  PColumnName FSchemaName FTableName  FColumnName ColumnOrder
emp         emphdr1     id          emp         empdtl1     hdrid       1
emp         emphdr2     id          emp         empdtl2     hdrid       1
emp         emphdr2     key         emp         empdtl2     hdrkey      2
emp         emphdr3     id          emp         empdtl3     hdrid       1
emp         emphdr3     key1        emp         empdtl3     hdrkey1     2
emp         emphdr3     key2        emp         empdtl3     hdrkey2     3
emp         emphdr3     id          emp         empdtl4     hdrid       1
emp         emphdr3     key1        emp         empdtl4     hdrkey1     2
```

Goal:

Dynamically create/output a SELECT statement - that JOINs FSchema/FTable with PSchema/PTable on (F/S)ColumnName in the order specified in ColumnOrder - in a new column.

query would be derived like..
"SELECT [F].[{FColumnName}], [P].[{PColumnName}] FROM [{FSchemaName}].[{FTableName}] AS [F] JOIN [{PSchemaName}].[{PTableName}] AS [P] ON [P].[{PColumnName}] = [F].[{FColumnName}] ;" (again, the ON clause is derived in the order specified in the [ColumnOrder] field)

Expected Output:

```
PSchemaName PTableName  FSchemaName FTableName  CMD
emp         emphdr1     emp         empdtl1     SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id] FROM [emp].[empdtl1] AS [F] JOIN [emp].[emphdr1] AS [P] ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid] ;
emp         emphdr2     emp         empdtl2     SELECT [F].[hdrid], [F].[hdrkey], [P].[id], [P].[key] FROM [emp].[empdtl2] AS [F] JOIN [emp].[emphdr2] AS [P] ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid] AND [P].[key] = [F].[hdrkey] ;
emp         emphdr3     emp         empdtl3     SELECT [F].[hdrid], [F].[hdrkey1], [F].[hdrkey2], [P].[id], [P].[key1], [P].[key2] FROM [emp].[empdtl3] AS [F] JOIN [emp].[emphdr3] AS [P] ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid] AND [P].[key1] = [F].[hdrkey1] AND [P].[key2] = [F].[hdrkey2] ;
emp         emphdr3     emp         empdtl4     SELECT [F].[hdrid], [F].[hdrkey1], [P].[id], [P].[key1] FROM [emp].[empdtl3] AS [F] JOIN [emp].[emphdr4] AS [P] ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid] AND [P].[key1] = [F].[hdrkey1] ;
```

My attempt:

I'm still trying to figure out a way. Concatenating a single column can be achieved by FOR XML, not sure how I would go about concatenating "=" between two columns and adding "AND" for joins with multiple columns..

Comment: It is probably not best to approach your underlying problem like this. You can write views or stored procedures which will return the data you require and will certainly be easier to maintain and tune.

Comment: @SteveFord, I'm not sure I understand your views/stored procedure thought process for what I'm trying to do. Could you please tell me more?

Comment: @007 you have asked how to run dynamic queries from a recordset, but you haven't explained what your problem is and why you are trying to solve it by storing queries in a table. Presumably if I have access to your application and can  write to this table I could potentially craft a SQL Injection attack! There are probably better approaches if you told us what you are trying to achieve overall.

Comment: Ah, understood. I'm trying to generate SELECT statements in bulk (based on data derived from another set of queries) that can be ran on-demand. This is an ad-hoc process and the output will not be stored anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Group By` and the `String_Agg` function, you can generate the desired output.

```
SELECT PSchemaName,PTableName,FSchemaName,FTableName,
      CONCAT('SELECT ',fselectcol,',',pselectcol,' FROM ',FTableName ,' f JOIN ',PTableName,' p ON ',joincol) AS CMD
FROM
(SELECT
       MAX(PSchemaName) AS PSchemaName,
       MAX(PTableName) AS PTableName,
       MAX(FSchemaName) AS FSchemaName,
       FTableName,
       STRING_AGG('p.' + PColumnName,',') pselectcol,
       STRING_AGG('f.' + FColumnName,',') fselectcol,
       STRING_AGG('p.' + PColumnName + ' = f.' + FColumnName,' AND ') joincol
FROM @Tbl_List
GROUP BY FTableName) t
```

**EDIT:** `SQL-SERVER 2016` does not support `String_Agg`, so use `XML PATH`

```
SELECT  
       MAX(PSchemaName) AS PSchemaName,
       MAX(PTableName) AS PTableName,
       MAX(FSchemaName) AS FSchemaName,
       FTableName,
       CONCAT('SELECT ',MAX(fselectcol),',',MAX(pselectcol),' FROM ',FTableName ,' f JOIN ',MAX(PTableName),' p ON ', SUBSTRING(MAX(joincol),0,LEN(MAX(joincol)) - 3)) AS CMD
FROM

(SELECT t1.*,
  STUFF(
    (SELECT ',p.' + PColumnName
     FROM @Tbl_List AS t2
     WHERE t2.FTableName = t1.FTableName
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS pselectcol,
   STUFF(
    (SELECT ',f.' + FColumnName
     FROM @Tbl_List AS t2
     WHERE t2.FTableName = t1.FTableName
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS fselectcol,
   STUFF(
    (SELECT 'p.' + PColumnName + ' = f.' + FColumnName,' AND '
     FROM @Tbl_List AS t2
     WHERE t2.FTableName = t1.FTableName
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, NULL) AS joincol
FROM @Tbl_List AS t1) T
GROUP BY FTableName
```

*demo in [db<>fiddle - sql server 2016](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=64288c10a6fd80405ee40e9d27b70bee)*

*demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0384f3d7f26d4ac3a4ca2e002c998b1)*

Comment: In 2016, which the OP explicitly tagged, you'll get an error: "'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name."...

Comment: Yes it is true I used xml path for Sql 2016

Comment: Amazing! Very interesting approach. Thank you!! Now I'll need to break it down to understand what this query is doing. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using a mix of Cross Apply and For Xml to generate the queries.

```
SELECT 
  [PSchemaName], [PTableName], [FSchemaName], [FTableName]
, [Cmd] = CONCAT('SELECT ', [Fields], char(10), 
                 'FROM ', [From], char(10), 
                 'JOIN ', [Join], char(10), [On])
FROM
(
  SELECT
     [FSchemaName], [FTableName], [PSchemaName], [PTableName]
   , [From] = CONCAT(QUOTENAME([FSchemaName]), '.', QUOTENAME([FTableName]), ' AS [F] ') 
   , [Join] = CONCAT(QUOTENAME([PSchemaName]), '.', QUOTENAME([PTableName]), ' AS [P] ') 
  FROM @Tbl_List
  GROUP BY 
     [FSchemaName], [FTableName], [PSchemaName], [PTableName]
) t
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT 
    [Fields] = STUFF(
    (SELECT ', [F].'+ QUOTENAME([FColumnName])
           +', [P].'+ QUOTENAME([PColumnName])
     FROM @Tbl_List t2
     WHERE t2.FTableName = t.FTableName
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, NULL)
  , [On] = '  ON' + STUFF(
    (SELECT  ' AND [P].'+ QUOTENAME([PColumnName])
         +' = [F].'+ QUOTENAME([FColumnName]) +char(10)
     FROM @Tbl_List t2
     WHERE t2.FTableName = t.FTableName
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 4, NULL)
  from @Tbl_List t2
  where t2.FSchemaName = t.FSchemaName
    and t2.FTableName = t.FTableName
) ca
```

| PSchemaName | PTableName | FSchemaName | FTableName | Cmd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp | emphdr1 | emp | empdtl1 | SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id]<br>FROM [emp].[empdtl1] AS [F] <br>JOIN [emp].[emphdr1] AS [P] <br> ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid]<br> |
| emp | emphdr2 | emp | empdtl2 | SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id], [F].[hdrkey], [P].[key]<br>FROM [emp].[empdtl2] AS [F] <br>JOIN [emp].[emphdr2] AS [P] <br> ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid]<br> AND [P].[key] = [F].[hdrkey]<br> |
| emp | emphdr2 | emp | empdtl2 | SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id], [F].[hdrkey], [P].[key]<br>FROM [emp].[empdtl2] AS [F] <br>JOIN [emp].[emphdr2] AS [P] <br> ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid]<br> AND [P].[key] = [F].[hdrkey]<br> |
| emp | emphdr3 | emp | empdtl3 | SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id], [F].[hdrkey1], [P].[key1], [F].[hdrkey2], [P].[key2]<br>FROM [emp].[empdtl3] AS [F] <br>JOIN [emp].[emphdr3] AS [P] <br> ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid]<br> AND [P].[key1] = [F].[hdrkey1]<br> AND [P].[key2] = [F].[hdrkey2]<br> |
| emp | emphdr3 | emp | empdtl3 | SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id], [F].[hdrkey1], [P].[key1], [F].[hdrkey2], [P].[key2]<br>FROM [emp].[empdtl3] AS [F] <br>JOIN [emp].[emphdr3] AS [P] <br> ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid]<br> AND [P].[key1] = [F].[hdrkey1]<br> AND [P].[key2] = [F].[hdrkey2]<br> |
| emp | emphdr3 | emp | empdtl3 | SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id], [F].[hdrkey1], [P].[key1], [F].[hdrkey2], [P].[key2]<br>FROM [emp].[empdtl3] AS [F] <br>JOIN [emp].[emphdr3] AS [P] <br> ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid]<br> AND [P].[key1] = [F].[hdrkey1]<br> AND [P].[key2] = [F].[hdrkey2]<br> |
| emp | emphdr3 | emp | empdtl4 | SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id], [F].[hdrkey1], [P].[key1]<br>FROM [emp].[empdtl4] AS [F] <br>JOIN [emp].[emphdr3] AS [P] <br> ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid]<br> AND [P].[key1] = [F].[hdrkey1]<br> |
| emp | emphdr3 | emp | empdtl4 | SELECT [F].[hdrid], [P].[id], [F].[hdrkey1], [P].[key1]<br>FROM [emp].[empdtl4] AS [F] <br>JOIN [emp].[emphdr3] AS [P] <br> ON [P].[id] = [F].[hdrid]<br> AND [P].[key1] = [F].[hdrkey1]<br> |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=61289124e1b2488392f278ffddf29391)*

Comment: THANK YOU @LukStorms for a great alternative. Really appreciate it. Cheers!!